# How to get data from Access to Excel, edit it an excel, and update back in Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am new to Access, what I want to do is to share few Excel templates with my colleagues which are linked to different tables in Access, they can refresh it to see the current data, and adjust it in Excel if they need to, then they press an update button in Excel which will save the data in the Access table 
I understand that I can get the data to Excel using
Data> Get Data> From DataBase> From Microsoft Access DataBase, but I need to understand how to update the Database from Excell

Comment: Why not create the templates in Access?  That way you do not need to do the back and forth.

Comment: Basically my team members are in different locations, and different time zones, I want basically to gather their input in Access, which I will be using later for reporting, Excel is easier for them to use

Comment: I think you are going to find this to be a LOT more difficult than you think. I've written VBA in the past to handle CRUD activity in a database table and it's no small feat. So far you have only solved the ***R***ead of CRUD. You still have to solve for the ***C***reate, ***U***pdate, and ***D***elete activities. I would agree that doing this in Access would be much easier. If you can do a `Get Data` then they can also open the database remotely (or a linked access database that has a form UI built to make it easy for them).

Comment: is it easier with SQL then ? the example in the following link is what I am after, https://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-sql-server-import-export-using-vba.htm

Comment: By the way, there will be no delete, only updates  to current fields

Comment: Using 'Get Data' only allows you to read data from the source, no other of the CRUD actions are possible.
Best would be to do it in a split Access database.